# JPA PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'STP_REFRESH_CATEGORY_GUARANTEE'

Tags: jpa, ora-06550

I am using JPA to call oracle stored procedure and getting below mentioned exception

## Error

```
[4/24/14 9:07:37:583 EDT] 00000031 SystemOut O [EL Warning]: 2014-04-24 09:07:37.452--UnitOfWork(1697919964)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'STP_REFRESH_CATEGORY_GUARANTEE'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Error Code: 6550
Call: BEGIN STP_REFRESH_CATEGORY_GUARANTEE(SHIP_CODE=>?, SAIL_DATE=>?, return_code=>?); END;
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: DataReadQuery(name="refreshCategoryGuarantee" )
[4/24/14 9:07:37:584 EDT] 00000031 SystemOut                                                    O         **********************************************************************************
[4/24/14 9:07:37:584 EDT] 00000031 SystemOut                                                    O EXCEPTION: Exception       [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'STP_REFRESH_CATEGORY_GUARANTEE'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Error Code: 6550
Call: BEGIN STP_REFRESH_CATEGORY_GUARANTEE(SHIP_CODE=>?, SAIL_DATE=>?, return_code=>?); END;
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: DataReadQuery(name="refreshCategoryGuarantee" ) ship_code: AL sail_date: 01-JUN-14
```

## Code :

```
    try{
                Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("refreshCategoryGuarantee");
                query.setParameter("SHIP_CODE", ship_code);
                query.setParameter("SAIL_DATE", DateUtil.getSqlDate(sailDate));
                return (Integer) query.getSingleResult();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("**********************************************************************************");
                logger.error("Error executing refreshCategoryGuarantee named query with param["+ship_code+","+sailDate+"] ", ex);
                return StoredProcedureConstants.RETURN_CODE_EXCEPTION;
           }
```

```
Here, refreshCategoryGuarantee is named query of STP_REFRESH_CATEGORY_GUARANTEE procedures.

-------------
<pre>
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(  
        name="refreshCategoryGuarantee",  
        procedureName="STP_REFRESH_CATEGORY_GUARANTEE",  
        returnsResultSet=false,  
        parameters={  
            @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="SHIP_CODE", type=String.class),  
            @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="SAIL_DATE", type=Date.class),  
            @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="return_code", direction=Direction.OUT, type=Integer.class) 
        })
```

My issue is, when i execute below mentioned anonymous block in oracle its working without any issue

```
    SET serveroutput ON
    DECLARE
      rc NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      STP_REFRESH_CATEGORY_GUARANTEE('OA','24-jan-15',rc);
      dbms_output.put_line('Response Code :'||rc);
    END;
```

I am not sure why I am getting this in JPA call? will you please some one help me to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Parameter SAIL_DATE's type in StoredProcedureParameter definition, is it java.util.date? It must be java.sql.date...

```
@StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="SAIL_DATE", type=java.slq.Date.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with accessing the parameters. Not by paramter names.

1 - get access to the EntityManager. E.g. via @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;

2 - use the NUMBERS to access the parameters. This is just an example.

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
.createStoredProcedureQuery("count_comments")
.registerStoredProcedureParameter(
    1,Long.class, ParameterMode.IN
)
.registerStoredProcedureParameter(
    2,Long.class, ParameterMode.OUT
)
.setParameter(1, 1L);
query.execute();
Long commentCount = (Long) query.getOutputParameterValue(2);
```